# Return authorization token with users credentials after sign in using devise-auth-token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

I am using devise-auth-token. It is working perfectly. I want when a user is signed in, she/she should get authorization not only in header section but also with the user fields. Following are the screen shots attached for everyone to understand it better.Authorization token is in the headers section and I want that in the user returning variables like under image or nickname.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/viJOf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go through `devise_token_auth`'s codebase, you can see how the tokens are generated [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/bef1b0b7172459dff0d0a23f8d911a7b23b9a6c7/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb#L29).

You can override the sessions_controller's `create` action like this:

```rb
def create
  super do
    render json: { user: current_user, 
                   token: @token }.to_json and return
  end
end
```

The `and return` prevents from `DoubleRenderError`.

It returns token along with your `current_user` in this format :

```
"token": {
        "client": "ZYUyzKCspyEN1dhUg",
        "token": "_y3JeRYQaEqH1cA",
        "token_hash": "ZGzsWyFNcmfoq5YlD9c2",
        "expiry": 166411321 
        }
```